# Problema com posicionamento de botão CSS

Tags: html, css

Bom dia! Estou enfrentando problemas com o posicionamento de um botão em CSS. Quando o formulário ainda não aplicou nenhuma validação, ele permanece na posição correta, porém quando as validações são aplicadas (é adicionada a classe `has-error` às divs e um label aparece embaixo do campo) ele se desloca para baixo, como na imagem abaixo.

[image: errocss]

Ao inspecionar os elementos, vejo que existe um padding no botão, e creio que removendo o `padding-top` iria resolver, porém não há sequer como editá-lo no navegador para visualizar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***EDIT - Código abaixo*** Estou usando Bootstrap 3

```
 <div class="form-group pesquisa">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <asp:Label
                            ID="lblCliente"
                            AssociatedControlID="txtPesquisaCliente"
                            ClientIDMode="Static"
                            Text="Cliente"
                            CssClass="col-lg-2 control-label"
                            runat="server">
                        </asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-9">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <asp:TextBox
                                ID="txtPesquisaCliente"
                                ClientIDMode="Static"
                                CssClass="form-control required"
                                runat="server">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="btnPesquisarCliente" class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Coloca o código, assim é difícil...

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois está ampla demais a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Victor coloca o trecho do seu código, fica mais fácil de entender o problema.

Comment: Olá! Perdão, tinha esquecido de inserir o código. Adicionado

Comment: Se retirares a `<div class="input-group-btn">` deve funcionar. Ou então alterar a `div` para `span`.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ambas as soluções propostas não resolveram. Retirando a class, o botão passa para a linha de baixo, e alterando a div para span o problema permanece o mesmo.

Comment: O Problema é que ele está inserindo o texto dentro do `input-group` por isso isto ocorre.

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos isso deve resolver seu problema http://jsfiddle.net/mapb_1990/hTPY7/7/

Comment: @DiegoVieira Abaixo a linha do JavaScript que adiciona a classe ao HTML
`$(element.form).find('div[class$="pesquisa"]').addClass('has-error');` Mesmo assim insere dentro do input-group? Obrigado!

Comment: Manda inspecionar o elemento quando receber essa classe e veja se está inserindo de fato dentro do `input-group`

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos tem como postar o seu css?

Comment: @DiegoVieira Vi aqui e não está inserindo

Comment: @RafaelTheodoro Uso somente o .css padrão do Bootstrap, nada personalizado. Como ultrapassa 1000 linhas, você pode consultar [aqui](http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css)

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos, Há alguns erros com o uso do grid ai, você está usando `col-lg-9` e `col-lg-12` dentro da mesma `div` o grande problema também está nesse `help-block` com o erro do campo, ele está inserindo antes do botão no grupo, consigo ver isto na segunda foto.

Comment: @DiegoVieira Já ocorre desta forma. Após a execução das validações, a única classe que recebe o `has-error` é a `form-group pesquisa`. Nenhuma outra classe a não ser esta recebe isso.

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos, Sim eu vi, engano meu, atualizei meu comentário.

Comment: @DiegoVieira O `col-lg-12` é do label do campo. Já o `col-lg-9` é do campo em si. Isso interfere? Quanto ao "help-block", há alguma forma de contornar este problema?

Comment: @VictorAlencarSantos Interfere no uso do grid, o jeito é tirar o `help-block` e colocar fora do `input-group`.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta adicionar esse script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if($('#someElement').hasClass('has-error')) {
        $(this).find('span').css("padding-top","0px");
    } 
});
```

Substitui '#someElement' pelo elemento que recebeu a class "has-error".

Comment: Olá Ana Claudia! Obrigado pelo código, porém o botão não está com nenhum padding, como você pode ver na segunda foto. Na visualização do CSS no navegador, a propriedade `padding` está com -, o que não posssibilita colocar nenhum valor

Comment: Verifica a linha abaixo, onde tem 'type="submit"' ou '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">'

Comment: já alterei o botão para asp:Button, onde não há a propriedade type, e não uso o span e o problema persiste. Creio que o problema seja outro, não? Obrigado!

Comment: seguindo o "ajuste"(gambiarra) da @Ana Claudia, vai testando ai, marging-top negativo, ou só top alterando o position relative ou absolute.